# initramfs-tools irqbalance apt-get upgrade error

Tags: apt, upgrade, amazon-ec2

I am getting an error when I do sudo apt-get upgrade. I did a do-release-upgrade and went into a lot of issues. Finally the problem has been reduced to:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up irqbalance (1.0.6-2ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript irqbalance, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package irqbalance (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-40-virtual
cp: skipping file ‘/lib/libc.so.5’, as it was replaced while being copied
cp: skipping file ‘/lib/libc.so.5’, as it was replaced while being copied
cp: skipping file ‘/lib/libc.so.5’, as it was replaced while being copied
cp: skipping file ‘/lib/libc.so.5’, as it was replaced while being copied
cp: skipping file ‘/lib/libc.so.5’, as it was replaced while being copied
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-40-virtual with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 irqbalance
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I don't suppose you ever found the solution to this error?

Answer (score -1):

The apt-get stopped, because of:

> Errors were encountered while processing:
>
> - **irqbalance**
> - **initramfs-tools**

Further up, you can read:

> Setting up irqbalance (1.0.6-2ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
>
> start: Job failed to start
>
> invoke-rc.d: initscript irqbalance, action "start" failed.

Therefore try either starting or stopping (if it's already started) `irqbalance` manually before starting the update.

If won't help, try re-installing it: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall irqbalance`.